# is there any guidance about how much traces should be available in released software which can still help in debugging majority of issues?

Tags: debugging, logging, trace

I am trying to develop a brand new multitasking software. This software will have multiple components and they will/can talk each other to get system working. Before release of this software to end users, we will run many round of validation to ensure good quality. During validation cycle our developers will be mainly relying on collected logs to troubleshoot and diagnose the issues. Since our debugging capability and time to market will be heavily dependent on collected traces, we will like to have as much as information available to developer at first hand. On the other hand if we add a lot of traces it will slow down our software and can eat many precious resources like CPU cycles etc. we will like to keep tracing/logging optimum. To solve this problem we want to provide guidance to our developer on judiciously using different log levels  e.g. debug, info, warning, error etc.  Here no of traces in debug > info > warning > error. we will like to start our validation cycle for software using say "info" level and gradually go to "warning" and "error" as software matures. Developers tend to put as much as traces they can so that they have all the information available. But as we will have multi-component system, total number of traces becomes very high and unmanageable leading to big log size, s/w performance issue etc. We want to give a generic guidance like if you have total 100 logs/traces for your component then say  100 should be available in debug, 70 should be available in Info, g", 10 should be available in error etc. So that we get a good quality of trace in first hand as well we keep control on total log/trace size. Is there any guidance/standard available, which we should use?

Answer (score 2):

You're unlikely to find any standard guides containing information about how to efficiently or effectively log. The fact is that every application has different requirements with regards to latency. There are some tricks you can employ to reduce your overhead. The points I'm mentioning here come from years of experience with highly concurrent software for which logging was a real bottleneck.

### Define Semantics and Make Them Configurable

Your post only gets as deep as describing some sort of hierarchy of log message types. Your question seems to be about whether there are best practices for limiting the overhead of these types. There are not, and this is because everybody needs different information at different times.

Let's assume your hierarchy of DEBUG < INFO < WARNING < ERROR < FATAL. (I introduced FATAL because you need one.) There are some best practices. They are best practices because they are common sense, not because an authority said so.

- FATAL messages correspond to events that are going to terminate your software. You always log these, no matter what. This behavior hopefully obviously does not need to be configurable.
- ERROR messages are things that have prevented your software from making expected progress, and it is *unlikely* that someone would have noticed.
- WARNING messages correspond to unexpected events, possibly events that prevented something from happening, but it is likely someone would have noticed.

The distinction between visibility is the real difference between WARNING and ERROR. ERROR is higher priority specifically because it is not visible. WARNING has a higher probability of being brought to your attention.

- INFO messages are purely informational, but their utility is largely for users of the software (as opposed to developers). These messages may include information about module start-up, version informations, etc. They are useful for understanding how a system is configured and its runtime state. They generally shouldn't be introduced as part of common runtime behavior.
- DEBUG messages are also purely informational, but their utility is for developers. When DEBUG messages are enabled, you want to log everything, always.

If you treat this as a hierarchy, your configuration lets you specify the minimum log level. The alternative is to treat them as options (i.e. "I want to log ERROR and INFO"). Either way, it may be useful to have different settings for different levels. But regardless, make them configurable.

Regarding DEBUG messages, it can be beneficial to break these down further in modular software. If you're concerned about DEBUG traces at customer sites including too much information, break down DEBUG messages into a per-component thing. Allow configuring e.g. DEBUG.subsystemA, DEBUG.subsystemB, etc.

### Use a Central Logger

At some point in your software, you need to actually put logs in a place. This should be done by a central service (library component, subsystem, whatever terminology makes sense for you) in your software.

Why centralize this? Many of the tricks you can employ to reduce the overhead of logging rely on being able to coordinate between multiple threads / tasks / whatever. It's easier to do this when log management is centralized. (Other approaches may end up requiring significant locking overhead, which sort of defeats the purpose.)

### Reduce Memory Allocation

Naïve approaches to logging tend to be extremely difficult on memory. Ephemeral log entries are constantly being allocated and freed, strings are being created and concatenated all the time, etc. Memory allocation isn't cheap, so we should start there.

- Define a maximum length of a log line and pre-allocate your log buffers. Much of the overhead of a naive logging solution comes from allocating and freeing memory to store log entries. In fact, log entries tend to be pretty ephemeral. If you can define a maximum length of a log entry, you can preallocate them, and use a pool of them to reduce allocation overhead through reuse.
- Many languages have immutable strings, and operations like concatenation that are common in logging end up having high overhead due to extra allocation. Use string building interfaces that do not have the overhead of allocating new objects every time a string operation happens.
- Somewhat relatedly, many languages have format specifiers for constructing strings. Format specifiers have high cost because format strings must be parsed at runtime, every time. Instead of using format specifiers, attempt to use a string building interface directly to avoid format specifier overhead.

### Rate Limit

When you've reduced the allocation overhead, you may still find that the overhead is prohibitive in some cases. If you've used a log entry pool, you will have an easy means to rate limit. If you have not (you should have, it's a good idea), you should consider rate limiting by itself.

With a log entry pool, when the pool is empty, you simply refuse to service new log entries. This effectively limits the rate. Otherwise, you'll need to define some kind of counter and use some kind of aging mechanism to determine the relevant immediate rate of messages you are logging.

Rate limiting should happen before format strings are parsed and before you had to do any allocations for things. Otherwise, you're paying additional overhead to not do anything.

### Batch Log Items

Queue your log items in a batch. This should be what you're already doing if you've created a centralized logging service in your software. Batching increases log latency, but reduces the immediate I/O overhead when your output is to a disk.

Make your flush interval configurable. Make your batch size configurable.

### Queue Items Asynchronously

If you're batching items, it's clearly already asynchronous, but just to spell it out: a log request for anything but a FATAL-level log item is a request that can wait a little bit to be logged. Much of the overhead of logging is due to I/O overhead, especially when the log destination is a disk or network endpoint.

### Provide Output Options

Logs don't have to go to files. They can go to network endpoints, files, or shared memory regions. Allow your users to define where logs go, and provide them with utilities or libraries to receive log items over those formats.

### Make Custom Trace Formats

Sometimes logging is too heavyweight for the task at hand. In some cases, custom trace formats can allow you to log where you were unable to before.

In our software at Fastly, threads take snapshots of their execution history and put them in a ring buffer that is exposed via tmpfs. These snapshots are strategically placed around locks and in a few key places in our main state machine.

The ring buffer is exposed to the software via a shared mapped memory region, and since it lives on a Linux `tmpfs`, all operations remain in-memory. These traces are always on, but require minimal overhead. By implementing it this way, we are able to get the level of debugging information in our production deployments that allows us to debug race conditions, deadlocks, and other problems.

---

The idea behind these sorts of optimizations is that it reduces the need for you to discard error messages in the first place. If you log appropriately and judiciously, and your logging infrastructure is properly designed, you will never be want for more information.

Comment: Interesting write up. Still, it'd be wise to additionally consider the security implications of what you are logging: you don't want to disclose too much of the internal workings of your application, and its failure modes, to a possible attacker. See https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/388.html

Comment: Information disclosure vulnerabilities are indeed worthy of consideration, but that will always boil down to an argument about acceptable risk versus one's ability to service the application. It's a worthy consideration, but a separate write-up, and one that definitely can draw from research.

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to make the logging level configurable at run time.  This is done by using a logging framework such as winston for javascript or an slf4j implementation for java.

Given that, I would let you developers work out on their own how much debug & trace information they need.  It's also usually pretty clear when an error needs to be logged.  So the only guidance / discussion we have is around how much info should be logged at the info level.  I would let the developers use their best judgement & then adjust as necessary, with the general guidance that stack traces for handled errors or data dumps should be done at debug or trace levels only.

When the system is deployed, the log level should be set to info or higher.  If an issue arises on a deployed system, the logging level can be increased temporarily to debug (or possibly higher) to allow the issue to be investigated.

Developers may run development systems with a debug or trace log level as the default.

During your validation cycle you can turn on debug logs as necessary to capture information.

Comment: thanks for adding your input. I am looking for some guideline, I can create as with my experience leaving it for developer, created a lot of traces/logs.

Comment: let the developers create lots of traces & debug logs.  Configure your production systems to error or info level.  problem solved.